# Device will not recognize commands or respond when communicating using PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, rs485

I am trying to communicate with an Omega CNi16D temperature controller using the PySerial module. Using the basic communication software provided by the manufacturer, I was able to write some settings to the controller, which ensures that I did the hardware configuration and settings correctly. However, I am having problems when I try to do this in Python 3.4 using PySerial. My suspicion is that I am not sending the byte code in an appropriate form. Here is what I tried:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, bytesize = 7, stopbits=1, timeout=0.1,\
       parity=serial.PARITY_ODD) #these are the settings on my controller
print(ser.isOpen())
ser.write(b'*01W01A003E8')
```

I get a True return from `isOpen()`, but nothing happens with the command. `*01W01A003E8` is one of the example commands given in the manual, where `*` is the recognition character, `01` is the slave address that I set on the controller side (I am using RS485), and `W01A003E8` is a hex-ASCII command to set the setpoint to -100.

Here are a few other things I tried with no success:
tried giving some sleep time before `ser.write()`; tried different commands that are supposed to return reading values from the controller, but I always get an empty byte object (`ser.read()` after whatever command returns `b''`.); tried switching to RS232 mode, which doesn't require a slave address in the command; tried `ser.write('*01W01A003E8'.encode('ascii'))` and also with `'utf-8'`.

I have a feeling that I am sending the wrong byte object to the controller. In the manual(`http://www.omega.com/Manuals/manualpdf/M3397.pdf` part.5), it sounds like I can just send in ASCII code in the specified format to make this work.

Comment: i am confused , `ascii` not required byte array . Where your line end delimeter ?(Ex: carriage return meaning `\r\n`) Don't use byte mode if using device on `ascii/no modbus` mode.

Comment: I think the `write()` method of PySerial requires a byte object as input. Is there another mode/method in PySerial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contemplating on the comment from "dsgdfg," I figured out the problem. It was a very simple thing. I was missing two things.

First, I should append the carriage return on the command. I somehow assumed that this would be implemented in the `write()` method, but I was wrong.

Second, it turns out that in order to get a response from the controller, I need to allow about 0.1 sec for the device to digest and respond back. In other words, `time.sleep(0.1)` before the `read()` command is requried.

Thanks for the helpful comment! As I was suspecting the wrong thing, I think I should change the title of the post.